# Не работает :hover SCSS

Tags: html, css, scss, hover

Не работает :hover. Тысячу раз уже проверил, пробовал разные варианты.

Код (HTML)

```
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro__inner">
                <div class="intro__left">
                    <div class="intro__title">
                        Get the most fun
                        weather app
                    </div>

                    <div class="intro__subtitle">
                        Simple, nice and user-friendly application of the weather. Only useful information
                    </div>

                    <div class="intro__buttons">
                        <a href="" class="intro__button" style="background-color: #fc6a42;">Download</a>
                        <a href="" class="intro__button" style="background-color: #4466c9;">Features</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="intro__right">
                    <img src="img/intro-phone.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="intro__bottom">
                    <a href=""><img src="img/intro-button.jpg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

SCSS

```
.intro {
    background: url("../img/intro-bg.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 959px;
    width: 100%;

    // .intro__inner

    &__inner {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    // .intro__left

    &__left {
        margin-bottom: -100px;
        width: 40%;
    }

    // .intro__title

    &__title {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Ubuntu;
        font-size: 60px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        text-align: left;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: normal;
    }

    // .intro__subtitle

    &__subtitle {
        margin: 42px 0 59px 0;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Ubuntu;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: left;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: normal;
    }

    // .intro__button

    &__button {
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 17px 30px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Ubuntu;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        text-align: left;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        transition: .6s linear;
        &:last-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
        margin-right: 13px;
        :hover {
            color: black;
        }
    }

    // .intro__right

    &__right {
        margin-bottom: -100px;
        width: 60%;
    }

    &__bottom {
        margin-bottom: -50px;
        a {
            height: 100%;
            img {
                transition: .3s linear;
                border-radius: 100px;
            }
            :hover {
                transform: translate(0, -10px) rotate(-360deg);
            }
        }

        
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.intro {
  background: url("../img/intro-bg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 959px;
  width: 100%;
}

.intro__inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.intro__left {
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  width: 40%;
}

.intro__title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}

.intro__subtitle {
  margin: 42px 0 59px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}

.intro__button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 17px 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-transition: .6s linear;
  transition: .6s linear;
  margin-right: 13px;
}

.intro__button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.intro__button :hover {
  color: black;
}

.intro__right {
  margin-bottom: -100px;
  width: 60%;
}

.intro__bottom {
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.intro__bottom a {
  height: 100%;
}

.intro__bottom a img {
  -webkit-transition: .3s linear;
  transition: .3s linear;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.intro__bottom a :hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -10px) rotate(-360deg);
          transform: translate(0, -10px) rotate(-360deg);
}
```

Comment: `&:hover {...}`

Comment: Заработало, но со свойством transform: translate(0, -30px); по прежнему не работает

Comment: Не надо использовать SCSS если не понимаешь основ CSS / Там кругом :hover к пустому месту присваивается. Как написал meine правильно писать &:hover  а в некоторых случаях привязывать к родителю

Answer (score 0):

для начала  убрать пробелы перед псевдоклассом :hover. Он же псевдо, он к "не псевдо" классу привязывается